# Parse JSON from HTML Python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I'm parsing out specific values on web pages with BeautifulSoup.  However, since I'm using RegEx, my program is taking forever to run.  Would love ideas on how to speed this up.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import json
from progressbar import progressbar
import pdb
import pickle
import re


class Listing():
    def __init__(self, custom_name, **entries):
        self.__dict__.update(entries)
        self.custom_name = custom_name
        self.date_accessed = datetime.datetime.today()

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.custom_name)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.custom_name == other.custom_name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.custom_name


def list_to_dict(rlist):
    # QUEST: There are multiple colons in many of the entries.  I couldn't
    # figure out how to use re.split where it only split the first occurence
    # so instead I replace only the first occurence and then split that new str
    list_with_replace_str = [re.sub(":", ":REPLACE", e, 1) for e in rlist]
    temp_dict = dict(f.split(":REPLACE") for f in list_with_replace_str)
    clean_dict = {}
    for key in temp_dict.keys():
        clean_key = key.strip()
        clean_value = temp_dict[key].strip()
        clean_dict[clean_key] = clean_value
    return clean_dict


def parse_listings(listing_objs):
    def parse_financials_div(financials_soup, listing_obj):
        try:
            financials_text = financials_soup.text
            financials_list = financials_text.split("\r\n")[:-1]
            financials_dict = list_to_dict(financials_list)

            not_included = []
            for key in financials_dict:
                if "*" in financials_dict[key]:
                    not_included.append(key)

            financials_dict["notIncluded"] = not_included

            for key in financials_dict:
                try:
                    financials_dict[key] = int(
                        re.sub("[^0-9]", "", financials_dict[key]))
                except Exception:
                    continue

            return financials_dict
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"error {e}")
            pdb.set_trace()

    def parse_details_div(details_soup, listing_obj):
        try:
            details_tag_list = details_soup.contents
            details_str = " ".join([str(element)
                                    for element in details_tag_list])
            details_list = details_str.split("<dt>")[1:]
            strs_to_tags = [BeautifulSoup(detail, "html.parser")
                            for detail in details_list]
            details_text = [tag.text for tag in strs_to_tags]
            details_dict = list_to_dict(details_text)

            return details_dict
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"error {e}")
            pdb.set_trace()

    def parse_category(product_json_soup, listing_obj):
        product_json_str = product_json_soup.contents[0].replace(
            "\r", "").replace("\n", "")
        product_json_str = product_json_str.replace(
            "\'", "").replace('\\"', '').replace("\t", "")
        product_dict = json.loads(product_json_str)
        category_str = product_dict["category"]
        category_list = category_str.split(">")
        category_list = [category.strip() for category in category_list]
        listing_obj.category = {}
        listing_obj.category["parent_category"] = category_list[0]
        try:
            listing_obj.category["sub_category"] = category_list[1]
        except Exception:
            listing_obj.category["sub_category"] = "Not Present"

    def parse_address(address_json_soup, listing_obj):
        address_json_str = address_json_soup.contents[0].replace(
            "\r", "").replace("\n", "")
        address_json_str = address_json_str.replace(
            "\'", "").replace('\\"', '').replace("\t", "")
        address_dict = json.loads(address_json_str)
        listing_obj.address = address_dict["address"]

    # Parse available listing fields into a dict
    print("Parse financials and details for listings")
    for listing_obj in progressbar(listing_objs):
        try:
            index = listing_objs.index(listing_obj)
            length = len(listing_objs)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(listing_obj.response_text, "html.parser")

            # Parse category
            category_json_pattern = re.compile(r"\"@type\" : \"Product\"")
            category_json_soup = soup.find(
                "script", {"type": "application/ld+json"}, text=category_json_pattern)
            if category_json_soup:
                parse_category(category_json_soup, listing_obj)

            # Parse address
            address_json_pattern = re.compile(r"LocalBusiness")
            address_json_soup = soup.find(
                "script", {"type": "application/ld+json"}, text=address_json_pattern)
            if address_json_soup:
                parse_address(address_json_soup, listing_obj)

            # Price details
            financials_span_pattern = re.compile(r"Asking Price:")
            financials_span_soup = soup.find(
                "span", text=financials_span_pattern)

            if financials_span_soup:
                financials_soup = financials_span_soup.parent.parent.parent.parent
                financials_dict = parse_financials_div(
                    financials_soup, listing_obj)
                listing_obj.financials = financials_dict
            else:
                print(
                    f"Financials not present #{index} of {length} {listing_obj.url}")
                print(soup)

            # Listing Details
            details_soup = soup.find("dl", {"class": "listingProfile_details"})
            if details_soup:
                details_dict = parse_details_div(details_soup, listing_obj)
                listing_obj.details = details_dict
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"error {e}")


def run_listing_calculations(listing_obj):
    # All in price
    extra_costs = 0
    price = listing_obj.financials["Asking Price"]
    for item in listing_obj.financials["notIncluded"]:
        if "Real Estate" not in item:
            extra_costs += listing_obj.financials[item]
    if isinstance(price, int):
        all_in_price = listing_obj.financials["Asking Price"] + extra_costs
    else:
        all_in_price = listing_obj.financials["Asking Price"]
    listing_obj.financials["allInPrice"] = all_in_price

    # Multiple
    all_in_price = listing_obj.financials["allInPrice"]
    cashflow = listing_obj.financials["Cash Flow"]
    try:
        listing_obj.financials["Multiple"] = all_in_price / cashflow
    except Exception:
        listing_obj.financials["Multiple"] = "N/A"


def parse_listings_from_pkl():
    with open("/Users/work/Dropbox/Projects/Working Data/bizbuysell/listings20191231.pkl", "rb") as infile:
        listing_objs = pickle.load(infile)

    print("Validate listing responses")
    listing_resp_validated = []
    for listing_obj in progressbar(listing_objs):
        try:
            if "Soup test failed" not in listing_obj.response_text:
                listing_resp_validated.append(listing_obj)
        except Exception:
            continue
    parse_listings(listing_resp_validated)
    print("Perform listing calculations")
    for listing_obj in progressbar(listing_resp_validated):
        financials_present = hasattr(listing_obj, "financials")
        if financials_present:
            run_listing_calculations(listing_obj)

    pdb.set_trace()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parse_listings_from_pkl()
```

Here's a [link to the `.pkl` file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/30lf2kmtx6evwzl/listings20191231.pkl?dl=0) needed to run this.

[Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/lancejohnson/b97469d8413d0bd8042aec80e3760af6) with the example HTML response and `product_json_soup`.

Comment: `product_json_soup` is undefined in your code. Add more context and post a testable `category_json_soup` content

Comment: Cleaned up the naming and added a gist with the responses to make it testable.

Comment: "program is taking forever to run" - there should be other bottlenecks on your side, the above fragment takes about 1 second to run on my machine. Does your actual script implies some looping and more extended parsing?

Comment: You're right @RomanPerekhrest.  It's fast for one, but when I iterate over 40,000 it is a very slow step.  I've added the ```cProfile``` for the larger program to the gist.  Let me know if that helps.  I could put in the entire function, but it's more or less just tweaks on this, and it seems the ```re``` operations take the longest.

Comment: Can you share those 40,000 urls so I could test the loop and get the actual estimates?

Comment: I'd guess that `requests.get` operations take the longest…

Comment: The `listings20191231.pkl` is too large (I don't know how many items inside). Please share a less one (e.g. 20..100 items) for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most time is consumed by `BeautifulSoup` conversions, namely

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(listing_obj.response_text, "html.parser")
```

For proof, firstly create a `.pkl` file of a *reasonable* size for debugging:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("D:\\Downloads\\listings20191231.pkl", "rb") as infile:
        listing_objs = pickle.load(infile)
    data = listing_objs[222:666]
    with open("D:\\Python\\CR\\listings20191231.pkl", "wb") as oufile:
        pickle.dump(data, oufile, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Then, check and compare consumed time using following adapted code (moreover, I removed all the `progressbar` stuff from the rest of original code):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import time
    import sys
    argcnt = len(sys.argv) - 1
    argtxt = 'parse_listings_from_pkl()' if argcnt == 0 else 'BeautifulSoup'
    startload = time.time()
    with open("D:\\Python\\CR\\listings20191231.pkl", "rb") as infile:
        listing_objs = pickle.load(infile)

    length = len(listing_objs)
    print( 'checking time: ', argtxt, length, 'records')
    start0 = time.time()
    if argcnt == 0:
        parse_listings_from_pkl()
    else:
        for listing_obj in listing_objs: #progressbar(listing_objs):
            soap = BeautifulSoup(listing_obj.response_text, "html.parser")

    start1 = time.time()
    print("time consumed: ", argtxt, start1 - start0)
```

**Output** shows that cca **86 % of time** (`100 * 32.761232137680054 / 38.00445818901062`) is consumed by converting original `html` to `BeautifulSoup` format:

```
D:\Python\CR\234876.py
```

> ```
> checking time:  parse_listings_from_pkl() 444 records
> Validate listing responses
> Parse financials and details for listings
> Perform listing calculations
> time consumed:  parse_listings_from_pkl() 38.00445818901062
> ```

```
D:\Python\CR\234876.py 1
```

> ```
> checking time:  BeautifulSoup 444 records
> time consumed:  BeautifulSoup 32.761232137680054
> ```

Although there are some *optimizable parts* in the rest of *pure `python` code* (and I tried them with only minor performance improvements), I found that the `BeautifulSoup` conversion time corresponds to original `html` size and there is most of *gubbins* of no use inside the analyzed `html`.

Hence, I'd try cutting the `listing_obj.response_text` into pieces of useful parts and convert merely those parts to `<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>` type. Maybe [Speeding up beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539330/speeding-up-beautifulsoup) or [Simple HTML and XHTML parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) could help extracting useful info from the original `html`?